# Pulseaudio static crackle in 5.1 analog

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, external-soundcard

I realize this is a repeated question, I just was not able to rectify the issue myself.

Anyways, I have a laptop running Ubuntu 13.04.  It does not have a 5.1 sound card installed, but I have 5.1 speakers.  So I purchased a USB sound card (Sound Blaster X Fi).

It works 'out of the box' with pulseaudio, only issue is any output other than stereo will cause static crackling.  I've attempted to remove pulseaudio and use ALSA with gnome-alsamixer and even xfe4-mixer, neither correctly installed and would revert to my laptops speakers.

Currently just running Pulseaudio in stereo output, but it's a waste.  If I can't fix this, probably going to go back to Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

In /etc/pulse/default.pa, change this line:

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

to:

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

This switches pulseaudio to the older scheduling mode and gets rid of the glitches.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Alas it does not

Comment: It does work for me, however. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I just found out that I can solve the problem in another way: changing the resample method on ```/etc/pulse/daemon.conf``` to ```resample-method = speex-float-1``` does the job as well, but works better for different programs.

Comment: Thanks, I have been gettin a TON of audio crackles on Arch here. It became very noticeable when trying to use Bitwig Studio and a midi controller, just unbearable when creating music. So I just tried this `tsched-0` and it didn't have an effect immediately, but I restarted and appears to have had a big difference. I have heard 1 crackle so far in about 10 minutes, not enough for LIVE usage but good for tinkering for now. Hoping this sticks and doesn't get worse with `uptime` increasing.

Comment: K, static crackle came back big time, 38 minutes of `uptime` now. I'll try the resample method next.

Comment: resample-method = speex-float-1 was commented out like `; resample-method = speex-float-1`, uncommented and ran `pulseaudio --kill` (which restarts it, I learned) and still have the crackle. I wonder if I should just switch to JACK or maybe it is something to do with my Thinkpad Thunderbolt dock that I am taking sound out into a mixer from.

Comment: I do somehow feel like this may be due to my previous usage of `paprefs` which allowed me to simultaneous output to my headphone jack and a USB speakerphone (multiple outputs). I uninstalled `paprefs` the other day because I got a Yamaha Mixer for this task which works better (paprefs would drift on the sync). And I seem to notice that the "simultaneous output" output is still present and should be gone. And when the crackle hits, my main Thinkpad output is completely gone from the system, although still visible with `alsamixer` and controllable there too.

Comment: Before I dig even further though, I am running everything on an old grounded outlet from a home built in 1950. So I'll try running an extension cord from a grounded outlet first, then next step is to update BIOS for the Thinkpad dock. Sorry to rubber duck here, not the right place.